# React redux pass state down to children

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm starting with React/Redux and I have a component that is like a wrapper for child components named `Filter`. This filter component has it's own state that I want to pass down to it's children elements.

```
export class Filter extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.node
    };

    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = function( state ) {
    return state.filter;
};

export default connect( (mapStateToProps), {
    doFilter: ( event ) => {
        return console.log(event.target.value);
    }
} )( Filter )
```

One of the children is supposed to call `doFilter` when it's value changes:

```
import Filter from 'components/filter';
....

export class CountryFilter extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Filter>
                <SelectField floatingLabelText="Country" value='all' fullWidth={true} onChange={this.props.doFilter}>
                    <MenuItem value='all' primaryText="All"/>
                    <MenuItem value='de' primaryText="Germany"/>
                    <MenuItem value='us' primaryText="United States"/>
                </SelectField>
            </Filter>
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is that `doFilter` is never called. If I do a log on `this.props` inside `CountryFilter` component it returns an empty object.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though the second argument in your `connect()` is an object, and not a function, which in turn accepts `dispatch` as an argument. [Here's the part of the doc](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) that mentions `mapDispatchToProps`. Now `mapDispatchToProps` can accept an object (and I believe the functions therein must be veritable Redux action creators), but I've typically seen it done with the following structure:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      foo: () => dispatch(<action>)
   }
}
```

Also, since we're binding `dispatch` to `props`, we'd most likely want to emit an action here as oppose to logging to console, however I suspect that was done just for debugging purposes.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        filter: state.filter
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        doFilter: (event) => (
           dispatch({
              type: 'SET_FILTER_VALUE',
              value: event.target.value
           })
        )
    }
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps)
(Filter);
```

Additionally, instead of emitting a simple object literal (i.e. `{type: 'SET_FILTER_VALUE', value: event.target.value`), we'd probably want to define this action else where in the form of an [action creator](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html), such as:

**actions.js**

```
const SET_FILTER_VALUE = 'SET_FILTER_VALUE';
const setFilterValue = (value) => {
   return {
      type: SET_FILTER_VALUE,
      value
   }
}
```

**Filter.jsx**

```
import { setFilterValue } from '../redux/actions';

...     

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        doFilter: (event) => (
           dispatch(
              setFilterValue(event.target.value)
           )
        )
    }
};

...
```

**EDIT 1**

Ah, looks as though we also aren't passing the props from `Filter` down to it's children, as a result `doFilter`/`setFilterValue` will be undefined. We'll use the following idiom to ensure `doFilter` is passed down. And from here, we can pass down anything we wish to any child:

**Filter**

```
render() {
    const doFilter = this.props.doFilter;
    return (
        <div>
            {
                React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
                    return React.cloneElement(
                        child, 
                        { doFilter: doFilter }
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**EDIT 2**

There was a request to show how the reducer and store creation might look for this example. And it might look as follows:

**store creation**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';

const initialState = {};

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState );
console.log(store.getState());
store.dispatch({type: 'SET_FILTER_VALUE', value: 2};
console.log(store.getState());
```

**Reducer**

```
const Reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_FILTER_VALUE': {
             return { 
                 ...state,
                 value: action.value
             }
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export default Reducer;
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. The `onChange` event does not propagate up to the parent component : `Filter`

Comment: Can you also paste code for where you define your store and your reducer for the filter part of the state?

Comment: Also @lux, awesome breakdown of that bit of Redux and how it works.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Just the answer updated with a snippet to add to filter's `render()`. This should ensure we're passing down the props from filter to its children

Comment: Awesome @lux, I really appreciate your detailed answer and effort here

Comment: @marcacyr Just added an edit on store creation and what the reducer might look like